# Cannot connect to localDB after creating from CMD

Tags: sql-server

So this is my first time setting up SQL Server 2014, I looked up online and try to make and connect to Local database, but it still gave me an error.

[Cannot Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rlPS.png)

Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **`(localdb)\SQLArra`** (with a **backslash** instead of forward slash) to connect. The SQL Server server+instance name **requires** a backslash and does **not** support forward slashes instead.

In my case (SQL Server 2016 LocalDB) this worked.